# Apply a "patch"/change to all python files in a project?

Tags: python, project

I have started a project in Python (2.7.6) where I download files from different sites.
Every site has it's own class and some functions in a different file.

So my working directory looks a bit like this:

```
/Sites
    - __init__.py
    - site1.py
    - site2.py
    - site3.py
    - ... 
    - siteN.py
/Tools
    - __init__.py
    - downloader.py
    - analyser.py
main.py
```

But for most sites I need to use different headers for urllib2. Normally I would just do:

```
html = urllib2.urlopen(embed_url).readlines()
```

But sometimes I need to change it to something like this:

```
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib2.Request(embed_url, None, headers)
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).readlines()
```

but doing this everytime for each file in the project, it seems like there has to be a better way. How could I generalize this "patch" for all the files in Sites, Tools but also in main.py whithout having to rewrite it in every file?

Maybe the title is a bit confusing, but I don't know how to explain it.

Many thanks already!

Comment: How do you find the place to change in each file? Is there a pattern?

Comment: Why are you doing it like this at all? Why not have a shared function in a central file that does the request?

Comment: @Tichodroma: I changed the question a bit, I hope it clearifies

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: so I should create a function in for example Tools and import it in every site.py and in the downloader and main.py etc?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming of course that we're always talking about the same line.

```
find -name *py -exec sed -i 's|html = urllib2.urlopen(embed_url).readlines()|headers =\n{'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}\nreq = urllib2.Request(embed_url, None, headers)\nhtml = urllib2.urlopen(req).readlines()\n|' {} +
```

I should warn you this line is gonna change your files without asking you for confirmation so you might consider running it without sed's -i (in place) flag and making sure you get the output you're expecting.